# c# way to setup application startup

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a C# Windows Form application that will have two modules:

1. POS Module
2. BackOffice Module

Both will be in the same installation but I would like to know what's the best way or practice to tell the installation whether or not to start as POS Module or as Backoffice Module.

I was thinking of having an XML file where I could input these arguments and on initialization of the application, it would read the XML file. Depending on the argument, it would then proceed to show either the POS Module or the BackOffice Module.

Comment: Would it be ok if both "modules" were under the same solution/project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command line argument. You can set shortcuts to include the argument as part of the command, so it's still just a double-click action to start the program in the correct mode.

Comment: Wooow I love that approach!! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that your "Modules" are under the same solution (a Windows Forms Template Project in this case).

When I have different projects that live under the same solution that need to be launched according to some sort of external parameter I use command line arguments.

For example (In Program.cs):

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{

    // If there are no args run default (Form1):
    if (args.Length < 0)
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1());
        return;
    }

    // If there are args check them
    foreach(var a in args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        switch(a)
        {
            case "aProject": 
                Application.Run(new Project());
                break;

            case "aDifferentProject":
                Application.Run(new ADifferentProject());
                break;
        }
    }
}
```